# Get Points for Particular Annotation MuPDF

Tags: android, pdf, annotations, mupdf

I am developing an application where I draw and save drawn coordinates in local db. When I redraw shape using db coordinates and erase one of it using following method,I want to erase those coordinates from db too. I am not able to get coordinates of erased shape. So If you can tell me how can I get the coordinates from `Annotation` object using MuPDF or any work around to do this that would be great.

```
MuPDFView pageView = (MuPDFView) mDocView.getDisplayedView();

if (pageView != null) {
 pageView.deleteSelectedAnnotation();
}
```